# What are the basic steps for training a model?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I have been put in charge of a ML employee. I have never worked with ML before.

He spends most of his time training models. We give him text files and the expected result, and he then trains his SVM model.

There are roughly two models to train each month.

This appears to be full-time work for him.

Could someone please tell me what are the basic steps for training a model? I would like to know if this really requires full-time attention!

We use Python.

Thanks

Comment: It involves running the model on a subset of the sample data, then using the unused data to check the accuracy of the model.  This process is called cross validation.  By the way, if you're asking this on SO then maybe you shouldn't be managing a data scientist.

Comment: Generally how long should it take to train two models? Each model has a few hundred text files as training data.

Comment: It depends on how much data you have.  Your only concern should be down time.  If each training run takes 4 hours, then maybe see what other tasks are available.

Answer (score 1):

The basic process to train a model involves following steps:

- Create a model
- Divide data into training and testing data sets
- Apply N-Fold Validation technique to remove data bias
- Check the accuracy of the model
- Repeat above steps until you get required accuracy.

It requires loads of repetition to get higher accuracy and fine tuning the model.

You hired a data scientist. Let him do his work!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Loading the Data
2. Pre-process/Clean the Data
3. Perform EDA
4. Treat Missing Values/Outliers
5. Split the Data
6. Scale the Data
7. One-Hot Enconding (if needed)
8. Train the data (fine-tune the params)
9. Evaluate the Model